# SparkR : collect data from R data frame doesn't work with RStudio

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, sparkr

I try to execute a very basic Spark action (`head()`) to collect the output from a Spark DataFrame that I created from a R data frame.
I want to do this in `yarn-client` deploy mode. I installed `R` on all nodes of the cluster.

When I run this application from `RStudio` by :

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/usr/local/spark160")
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))

sc <- sparkR.init(master="yarn-client", appName = "Spark Test",
                  sparkHome = "/usr/local/spark160/")
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, iris) 
head(df)
```

I get this error on each nodes

> Java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out

But when I run the same code from the `SparkR` shell directly (always in `yarn-client`) everything works.

I noticed that this difference doesn't occur, for me, when I want to collect DataFrame from HDFS or HIVE sources.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not RStudio, problem is when you start execution like below (please try everything on terminal)

```
$ R
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/usr/local/spark160")
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))

sc <- sparkR.init(master="yarn-client", appName = "Spark Test", sparkHome = "/usr/local/spark160/")
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, iris) 
head(df)
```

I know the alternate solution that I got to work.
Try below on terminal:

```
$ /usr/local/spark160/bin/sparkR --master yarn-client
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, iris) 
head(df)
```

Starting R with above will start R along with Spark Context (sc) and SQLContext (sqlContext), and you should be able to run it and get results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the inclusion of `master="yarn-client"` in your R script.

In general, there are two (2) distinct and different ways to run SparkR scripts:

1. Interactively (e.g. through RStudio) or as "pure" R scripts (i.e. with the `source()` command); in this case, your code should be like that:

   ```
   Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/usr/local/spark160")
   library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))

   sc <- sparkR.init(appName = "Spark Test", sparkHome = "/usr/local/spark160/") # no 'master' argument
   sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
   df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, iris) 
   print(head(df))
   #   Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species
   # 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
   # 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
   # 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
   # 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
   # 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
   # 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
   sparkR.stop()
   ```
2. As Spark applications, i.e. with `spark-submit`, in which case again you do not include the `master` argument in the script - you use it as an argument in `spark-submit`. The script could again be as above, but in the general case you would probably like to include extra arguments for the Spark executors & cores, so your `SparkR.init()` command would look something like

   ```
   sc <- sparkR.init(appName = 'Spark Test',
                     sparkEnvir = list(spark.executor.cores='2',          
                                      spark.executor.instances='2'))
   ```

Now, if you save this script as `sparkr_test.R`, you should run it from the shell as

```
$ spark-submit --master yarn-client --driver-memory 2g /path/to/sparkr_test.R
[...]
   Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Notice also that the `driver-memory` argument, too, should go with `spark-submit` and not in the script.

(I have written a more detailed guide regarding SparkR [here](http://www.nodalpoint.com/sparkr-in-cloudera-hadoop/)).